# Does ASP.NET use reflection to check for existance of event handlers?

Tags: asp.net, events, reflection, event-handling, markup

I create an asp.net page e.g. default.aspx.

I then define a button...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" Text="New" OnClick="btnNew_OnClick" />
```

... however I do *not* define the handler for btnNew_OnClick in code.

ASP.Net will tell me this when I start the page and throw an exception.

Therefore, does it use reflection to check if the class that implements my page has this method ?

Is this efficient if it has to do this each time it parses a page's markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specifically. This happens when ASP.NET [compiles your ASPX markup](http://odetocode.com/articles/417.aspx). ASPX markup is compiled the first time the page is hit on the fly, and stored somewhere in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

The exception to that is if you precompile your pages using `aspnet_compiler.exe`. However, if you were to pre-compile it you'd see there error there, not when you hit the site.

> Is this efficient if it has to do this each time it parses a page's markup?

ASP.NET isn't parsing the markup on every page view and post back; it's only parsing it once when it's compiled. It stored a hash of the page (usually called `hash.web` somewhere in Temporary ASP.NET Files) and compares the hashes. If the hash is different (the page changed) then it recompiles it. Here is an example of what that compiled code may look like:

```
#line 58 "C:\X\UserControls\FilterControl.ascx"
@__ctrl.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.btnApply_Click);

#line default
#line hidden

#line 58 "C:\X\UserControls\FilterControl.ascx"
@__ctrl.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnApply_Click);
```

This of course gets compiled into an executable assembly. Effectively, what the ASPX compiler is doing is compiling the server side markup into C# code, then compiler that into an assembly.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET actually generates a class descending from your page using the ASPX markup as a template of sorts. You can find the generated classes source code in the folders under %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\v[FRAMEWORK VERSION]\Temporary ASP.NET File.

My understanding is it generates a class which instantiates the control and wires the event handlers to whatever method applies. This is why things break badly when you, say, make your event handler private -- the descendant class can't access it.

The code generation is pretty expensive up-front; it is partially responsible for that lengthy asp.net warm-up most of us asp.net developers suffer through. But it is very, very efficient once the app gets warmed up as everything is rendering via compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not use reflection. As @Wyatt Barnett said, the compiler generates code for this. The generated code is the same as if you would register the event yourself.

```
btnNew.Click += new EventHandler(btnNew_Click);
```

As the code for the markup is generated it is the same regarding performance, maybe except for the first call.